# How to set inputViewStyle on UIInputView (initialized in XIB)?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm implementing a view above the keyboard with some additional buttons.
I saw that you can use UIInputView like this:

```
let keyboardAccessoryView = UIInputView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 40), inputViewStyle: .keyboard)
textView.inputAccessoryView = keyboardAccessoryView
```

The result looks good (matches the background in both light and dark mode).

I'd prefer if I could define the interface in a XIB though, I find that easier. But the property `inputViewStyle` is read-only, so it seems you can only set the inputView style during initialization.

I tried subclassing `UIInputView` and overriding `inputViewStyle` but that doesn't change the style for some reason.

Is there a way to init this with the `.keyboard` style and still use a xib?

Comment: With your question, try to be a little more detailed about what you are doing. Show some relevant code... make take a look at [mre].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can load your XIB view and add it as a subview to your `UIInputView`:

```
class InputTestViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let keyboardAccessoryView = UIInputView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 40), inputViewStyle: .keyboard)

        // I have MyInputView configured to load itself from a XIB
        let v = MyInputView()

        // add it to the UIInputView
        keyboardAccessoryView.addSubview(v)

        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: keyboardAccessoryView.topAnchor),
            v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: keyboardAccessoryView.leadingAnchor),
            v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: keyboardAccessoryView.trailingAnchor),
            v.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: keyboardAccessoryView.bottomAnchor),
        ])

        textView.inputAccessoryView = keyboardAccessoryView

    }

}

class MyInputView: UIView, NibLoadable {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupFromNib()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupFromNib()
    }

}

public protocol NibLoadable {
    static var nibName: String { get }
}

public extension NibLoadable where Self: UIView {

    static var nibName: String {
        return String(describing: Self.self) // defaults to the name of the class implementing this protocol.
    }

    static var nib: UINib {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: Self.self)
        return UINib(nibName: Self.nibName, bundle: bundle)
    }

    func setupFromNib() {
        guard let view = Self.nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as? UIView else { fatalError("Error loading \(self) from nib") }
        addSubview(view)
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.frame = self.bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    }
}
```

Here's how my custom view looks in IB (four buttons in a horizontal stack view):

[image]

and here's how it looks at run-time:

[image]

Comment: Ah, it didn't occur to me I can just add it as a subview ‍♂️. Thank you!!